# Averages by Time in R

Tags: r, time, average, analysis, seconds

I have compounds concentrations measured every second. I want to make 30 and 60 seconds averages. I have been reading the posts here, I tried `lubridate` and `dplyr`. But no luck. I am trying to make this work, but I have not been able to do so. i am transitioning from SAS to R, so please be patient.

This is my data:

```
head (data)#show the first 6 rows

   Date     Time  Temp      Appb    Bppb    Cppb     Dppb    Eppb      Fppb

1 10/30/17 21:32:33 25.23 -0.469304 22.4445 35.5993 -18.4843 52.0488 -2.947340   
2 10/30/17 21:32:34 25.23 -1.255780 21.8248 34.2364 -20.9051 47.4344 -2.071230  
3 10/30/17 21:32:35 25.23 -0.769233 21.1590 30.5892 -20.9347 42.6061 -0.991607  
4 10/30/17 21:32:36 25.23 -0.874262 21.3353 25.4841 -19.6127 38.3224 -0.452383  
5 10/30/17 21:32:37 25.24 -0.819439 21.1916 21.4919 -16.5991 36.1331 -0.150002  
6 10/30/17 21:32:38 25.24 -1.895730 21.5345 18.0576 -17.2539 31.7448 -0.311064
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can do the following:

```
data$time_bucket <- 
  as.POSIXct(round(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(paste(data$Date, data$Time), format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"))/30)*30, origin='1970-01-01')
```

This might seem a bit involved but it does the following:

1. `as.POSIXct(paste(data$Date, data$Time), format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")` paste together the date and time columns to create one "datetime" object.
2. `as.numeric` converts it to "epoch" number - number of seconds since 1970-01-01
3. Divide by 30, round and multiply by 30 - this will created buckets of 30 seconds. All times that round to the same number will have the same "label" after the rounding.
4. Finally convert it to "datetime" using `as.POSIXct`.

After you have done all this you can just take the average by time bucket, for example using `dplyr`:

```
data %>% group_by(time_bucket) %>%
  summarize(mean(Temp))
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` and `lubridate` approach for completeness.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

dat <- read.table(text = "Date     Time  Temp      Appb    Bppb    Cppb     Dppb    Eppb      Fppb
                          1 10/30/17 21:32:33 25.23 -0.469304 22.4445 35.5993 -18.4843 52.0488 -2.947340   
                          2 10/30/17 21:32:34 25.23 -1.255780 21.8248 34.2364 -20.9051 47.4344 -2.071230  
                          3 10/30/17 21:32:35 25.23 -0.769233 21.1590 30.5892 -20.9347 42.6061 -0.991607  
                          4 10/30/17 21:32:36 25.23 -0.874262 21.3353 25.4841 -19.6127 38.3224 -0.452383  
                          5 10/30/17 21:32:37 25.24 -0.819439 21.1916 21.4919 -16.5991 36.1331 -0.150002  
                          6 10/30/17 21:32:38 25.24 -1.895730 21.5345 18.0576 -17.2539 31.7448 -0.311064   ",
                  header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

#convert to R date object 
dat$tme <- as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(dat$Date, dat$Time), format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"), tz = "America/Montreal")

#convert to data.table
dat <- as.data.table(dat)

#drop Date and Time since we have an R date object now
dat <- dat[,-c(1,2)]

#result
dat[, lapply(.SD, mean), .(tme = round_date(tme, "3 seconds"))]
```

I rounded to 3 seconds since the sample data was all within 30 seconds (same as the above answer).

Here are the results:

```
    tme     Temp      Appb     Bppb     Cppb      Dppb     Eppb       Fppb
1: 2017-10-30 21:32:33 25.23000 -0.862542 22.13465 34.91785 -19.69470 49.74160 -2.5092850
2: 2017-10-30 21:32:36 25.23333 -0.820978 21.22863 25.85507 -19.04883 39.02053 -0.5313307
3: 2017-10-30 21:32:39 25.24000 -1.895730 21.53450 18.05760 -17.25390 31.74480 -0.3110640
```

I personally prefer the `data.table` approach especially for larger datasets due to its speed and how convenient it is to subset and perform operations.

Comment: When you type dat<-read.table... Do you have to write all the numbers? My file contains more than 6500 rows.  I am sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: It's alright. I was using your sample data that's why it's written like that. Depending on the data format, you read the raw dat directly into R. For example, if you have a .csv/.txt file you can use fread() from the data.table package which is really fast. There's the read_xlsx from xlsx package for MS excel files. You can also read data via an API call if your data is online.

Comment: Thank you. This what I have been doing.                                              data <-read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
#as.is read time
attach(data)
data
head (data)#show the first 6 rows
str(data)#show type of data

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution with `period.apply` from `xts`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(xts)

data_ts = as.xts(data[-c(1:2)], mdy_hms(paste(data$Date, data$Time)))

ep = endpoints(data_ts, 'seconds', k = 30)

period.apply(data_ts, ep, FUN = mean)
```

**Result:**

```
                        Temp      Appb     Bppb     Cppb      Dppb    Eppb      Fppb
2017-10-30 21:32:38 25.23333 -1.013958 21.58162 27.57642 -18.96497 41.3816 -1.153938
```

Since all your sample data is within 30 seconds, you only get one average for each column. To verify that my answer actually works, you can try a 2-second mean:

```
test_ep = endpoints(data_ts, 'seconds', k = 2)

period.apply(data_ts, test_ep, FUN = mean)
```

**Result:**

```
                      Temp       Appb     Bppb    Cppb     Dppb     Eppb       Fppb
2017-10-30 21:32:33 25.230 -0.4693040 22.44450 35.5993 -18.4843 52.04880 -2.9473400
2017-10-30 21:32:35 25.230 -1.0125065 21.49190 32.4128 -20.9199 45.02025 -1.5314185
2017-10-30 21:32:37 25.235 -0.8468505 21.26345 23.4880 -18.1059 37.22775 -0.3011925
2017-10-30 21:32:38 25.240 -1.8957300 21.53450 18.0576 -17.2539 31.74480 -0.3110640
```

**Data:**

```
data = read.table(text = "   Date     Time  Temp      Appb    Bppb    Cppb     Dppb    Eppb      Fppb
                  1 10/30/17 21:32:33 25.23 -0.469304 22.4445 35.5993 -18.4843 52.0488 -2.947340   
                  2 10/30/17 21:32:34 25.23 -1.255780 21.8248 34.2364 -20.9051 47.4344 -2.071230  
                  3 10/30/17 21:32:35 25.23 -0.769233 21.1590 30.5892 -20.9347 42.6061 -0.991607  
                  4 10/30/17 21:32:36 25.23 -0.874262 21.3353 25.4841 -19.6127 38.3224 -0.452383  
                  5 10/30/17 21:32:37 25.24 -0.819439 21.1916 21.4919 -16.5991 36.1331 -0.150002  
                  6 10/30/17 21:32:38 25.24 -1.895730 21.5345 18.0576 -17.2539 31.7448 -0.311064", 
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually got it to work, with the exception of the Data part. My data set contains 6,500 rows. I do not understand if I have to write each single data point.